# jxBrowser java bridge is not calling method in superclass

Tags: jxbrowser

I have the latest jxBrowser.  I´m trying to interface jxBrowser with the NetCDF-Java library.  I have instanciated an NetCDF Array on Java and set it into jxBrowser.  When calling a method on this class, I get the correct answer, so, everything is working fine.  However, when calling a method on the superclass I get an exception (the method is toString()):

01:51:30 INFORMAÇÕES: WRITE: OnInvokeJSJavaMessage{type=OnInvokeJSJavaEvent, uid=7, javaObjectId=0, contextPtr=68553440, methodName='toString', parameters='', returnValue='', errorMessage='NoSuchMethodException: ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$D2.toString()'}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}
01:51:30 INFORMAÇÕES: READ:  ExecuteJavaScriptMessage{type=ExecuteJavaScript, uid = 21, frameId=-1, javaScript='        var dbl2 = dbl.toString();
', hasReturnValue=true, returnValue=''}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}
01:51:30 INFORMAÇÕES: [0620/175130:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught NoSuchMethodException: ucar.ma2.ArrayDouble$D2.toString()", source:  (1)

toString is defined on ucar.ma2.Array (from the documentation):

public java.lang.String toString()
Overrides:
toString in class java.lang.Object

Did I do something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Right now JxBrowser JavaScript-Java Bridge allows binding Java classes to JavaScript objects directly. It doesn't support calls to super class methods. In one of the next versions this functionality will be extended and support of super classes will be implemented.

Comment: UPD: this functionality was introduced in JxBrowser 6.6.1: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000016673